# Downloading Oracle forms and reports 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oraclereports

Can anyone please suggest some useful weblinks for downloading for free Oracle forms and Reports 11G.
 Also suggest the perquisites for installation.

Comment: Please avoid asking such questions...The answer that you want is in the official site...http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

You first need to create an account in oracle.com

Then you can go to below link that has all the downloadable software by Oracle

https://edelivery.oracle.com/osdc/faces/Home.jspx